# Around workaround

Tags: numerics

I'm testing `Around` for error propagation (v12.2), but it seems to be inconsistent.
Error results depend on the form. Am I missing something here?

**Edit**
Same results in wolfram cloud, which has v12.3.

```
ClearAll[get$amplitude] ;
get$amplitude[frequency_, signal_] := Block[
  {c, s},
  c = Cos[2*Pi*frequency*Range[Length[signal]]] ;
  s = Sin[2*Pi*frequency*Range[Length[signal]]] ;
  c = 2.0*Dot[signal, c] ;
  s = 2.0*Dot[signal, s] ;
  Divide[{Norm[{c, s}], Sqrt[c^2 + s^2], Sqrt[c*c + s*s]}, Length[signal]]
] ;

frequency = 0.12 ;
signal = 0.5*Sin[2*Pi*frequency*Range[256]] ;
signal = Around[signal, 0.1] ;
TableForm[Map[FullForm, get$amplitude[frequency, signal]]]
(* Around[0.501507305064027`,0.008852097698515098`] *)
(* Around[0.501507305064027`,0.008852097698515098`] *)
(* Around[0.501507305064027`,0.006259378310345857`] *)
```

Here is a torch implementation, I was expecting results to match exactly.
What can be the reason behind this mismatch? Looks like `Around` doesn't use automatic differentiation, I thought it uses `Series` under the hood.

```python
import torch
from math import pi

pi = torch.tensor(pi, dtype=torch.float64)
length = 256
time = torch.linspace(start=1.0, end=length, steps=length, dtype=torch.float64)
signal = 0.5 * torch.sin(2.0 * pi * 0.12 * time)
signal.requires_grad_(True) ;

def get_amplitude(length, frequency, time, signal):
  c = torch.cos(2.0 * pi * frequency * time)
  s = torch.sin(2.0 * pi * frequency * time)
  c = 2.0 * torch.dot(c, signal)
  s = 2.0 * torch.dot(s, signal)
  return torch.sqrt(c*c + s*s) / length

amplitude = get_amplitude(256, 0.12, time, signal)
amplitude.backward()

sigma = 0.1*0.1 + torch.zeros(length, dtype=torch.float64)
sigma = torch.diag(sigma)
print(amplitude.item())
print(torch.sqrt(torch.dot(signal.grad, sigma @ signal.grad)).item())
# 0.501507305064027
# 0.008852294777182603
```

Comment: `Around` was reimplemented in V12.3. This information may not be valuable for you, but it may also have fixed the issues you are having.

Comment: @CATrevillian, could you test WM code in V12.3, do the results match?

Comment: I'm running 12.3.1 and my results match what you show for WM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be because (since `Around` represents statistical uncertainty) it tries to figure out which expressions are correlated and which ones are uncorrelated. In general, `Around[x, a]^2` is different than `Around[x, a] * Around[x, a]`, since in the former, we're drawing from the same distribution, but in the latter, we're drawing from two uncorrelated distributions.

```
Around[x, a]^2

(* Out: Around[x^2, 2 Abs[a x]] *)

Around[x, a] * Around[x, a]

(* Out (upon simplifying): Around[x^2, Sqrt[2] Abs[a x] *)
```

Likewise for addition:

```
2 Around[x, a]

(* Out: Around[2 x, 2 a] *)

Around[x, a] + Around[x, a]

(* Out (upon simplifying): Around[2 x, Sqrt[2] Abs[a]] *)
```

It's a bit clunky, but to avoid this, it seems like you need to use `AroundReplace`:

```
AroundReplace[z + z, {z -> Around[x, a]}]

(* Out (upon simplifying): Around[2 x, 2 Abs[a]] *)

AroundReplace[2 z, {z -> Around[x, a]}]

(* Out (upon simplifying): Around[2 x, 2 Abs[a]] *)
```

Note that these actually seem to agree "anyway" because `z + z` gets simplified to `2 z` first. But the documentation assures us that `AroundReplace` "does what we want" and considers two instances of the same replaced variable as coming from the same distribution, and tells us to contrast the following as an example:

```
expr = p q/(p + q);
rules = {p -> Around[p0, \[Delta]p], q -> Around[q0, \[Delta]q]};
$Assumptions = (p | q | p0 | q0 | \[Delta]p | \[Delta]q) \[Element] 
   Reals;
AroundReplace[expr, rules] // Simplify
ReplaceAll[expr, rules] // Simplify
```

(Note that `AroundReplace` supports `VectorAround` when we want to consider the uncertainties of the entries in a vector to be correlated with each other.)

So, a workaround for your particular function might consist of giving it this definition for a list of `Around`'s:

```
ClearAll[get$amplitude]
get$amplitude[frequency_, signal : {___Around}] :=
 Block[
  {c, s, c0, s0},
  c = Cos[2*Pi*frequency*Range[Length[signal]]] ;
  s = Sin[2*Pi*frequency*Range[Length[signal]]] ;
  c = 2.0*Dot[signal, c] ;
  s = 2.0*Dot[signal, s] ;
  AroundReplace[
   Unevaluated[
    {Norm[{c0, s0}], Sqrt[c0^2 + s0^2], Sqrt[c0*c0 + s0*s0]}/Length[signal]], {c0 -> c, s0 -> s}]
]
```

One problem is that Mathematica apparently doesn't know that `Derivative[1][Abs][x]` is `1` for `x > 0`:

```
frequency = 0.12;
signal = 0.5*Sin[2*Pi*frequency*Range[256]];
signal = Around[signal, 0.1];
TableForm[Map[FullForm, get$amplitude[frequency, signal]]]

(* Out: *)

Around[0.501507305064027`,Power[Plus[Times[1.734130926267436`*^-9,Power[Derivative[1][Abs][0.6057819465394019`],2]],Times[0.00007835789953313003`,Power[Derivative[1][Abs][128.38444091337783`],2]]],Rational[1,2]]]
Around[0.501507305064027`,0.008852097698515098`]
Around[0.501507305064027`,0.008852097698515098`]
```

@Lukas Lang identified a better way to resolve the issue in a comment: append  `/. {Abs -> RealAbs}` to the result (as Mathematica assumes `Abs` is a function on the compelxes, which is not holomorphic, and so doesn't have a simple derivative that behaves nicely), and it'll work itself out.

Comment: Thanks, this explains the difference in WM code. Looks like one should be careful using `Around` in expressions. Still need to wrap my head around which case is 'correct'. For `torch` approximate formula is used sigma_f^2 = grad(f) var(x) grad(f) , this might explain the difference, since in WM it's more like using variance-covariance

Comment: Regarding the issues with `Abs`: The issue is that the complex derivative of `Abs` is not well-defined, hence the issues. You can simply use `/.Abs->RealAbs`  to replace it with `RealAbs`, which does not have these problems

Comment: Gotcha. Interesting that it doesn't have a downvalue defined on `Reals` (without `0`), though. I think that would be useful!